# Using distinct in Spring data over multiple columns

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My domain model is like this:

```
CollectedData {
  String name;
  String description;
  int count;
  int xAxis,
  int yAxis
}
```

Using Spring data repository query, I would like to retrieve all the unique rows (unique with name, xAxis, yAxis)

I am trying something like this

```
@Query("select distinct a.name, a.xAxis, a.yAxis from CollectedData a")
List<CollectedData> findAllDistinctData();
```

So, when I do

```
List<CollectedData> records= findAllDistinctData();
for (CollectedData record : records) { //Exception on this line
 }
```

Exception
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to CollectedData.

Is there any other way to write query for this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Query return `ArrayList of Object(s)` instead of specific type of object. so you have to define some thing like

```
@Query("select distinct a.name, a.xAxis, a.yAxis from CollectedData a")
List<Object> findAllDistinctData();
```

then cast according to your requirement,

```
List<Object> cdataList=findAllDistinctData();
for (Object cdata:cdataList) {
   Object[] obj= (Object[]) cdata;
     String name = (String)obj[0];
    String description = (String)obj[1];;
 ...
  }
```

Comment: Additional and important remark. Simply use a very straightforward REST controller and avoid using Spring Data when using distinct for multiple columns.

Comment: In my case, I needed to convert `List<Object>` returned by `@Query` to `List<MyInterface>` where `MyInterface` is a java interface.  I could not use any other way but this worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning an object you can use JPA's constructor expression feature to return a more specific object holding only the columns you're interested in. See also following answer:

[JPQL Constructor Expression - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:Table is not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271305/jpql-constructor-expression-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexceptiontable-i)

According to your example you could create a new Object with only the columns you are interested in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT new com.mypackage.MyInterestingCollectedData(a.name, a.xAxis, a.yAxis) from CollectedData a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select **complete object** based on distinct values of multiple columns,

In that case the native query would be the option.

e.g.

```
@Query(
        value = "select distinct on (column1, column2, column3) * From my_table where someId=: order by column1 asc,column2 desc,column3 desc,column4 desc",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun finalAllDistinctBy(containerId: String): List<MyTable>
```