# How can I use a wrapper object as a JPA entity without having a corresponding table in the database

Tags: jpa, wrapper, jpql

I am building a system on top of an existing (old and messy) database. For this I'm building a JPA layer above the database, but I do not want to map my domain objects directly to the existing database tables.

I currently have a wrapper object that encapsulates 4 entities (data from 4 tables) in the database. Is there a way I can use this wrapper class as a parameter in a JPQL query?

It would be great if the wrapper class itself acted somewhat like a JPA entity, but without having the corresponding database table. Can this be achieved, and if so, how?

---

For example, how should I change `Wrapper`

```
public class Wrapper {
    private FirstJpaEntity first;
    private SecondJpaEntity second;
}
```

so that I can use something like

```
List<Wrapper> wrappers = ...;

TypedQuery<Wrapper> query = entityManager.createQuery(
              "SELECT wrap" // This is probably where the problem lies: JPA needs a Type for `wrap`, but this type needs to be an @Entity which `wrap` is not
            + " WHERE wrap IN :wrappers"
            + "   AND wrap.first.property = 1"
            + "   AND wrap.second.property = 2"
            , Wrapper.class);

query.setParameter("wrappers", wrappers);
```

---

I looked into making Wrapper an @Embeddable, hoping JPQL could figure out how to navigate through it, but alas [@Embeddable objects cannot be queried directly.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Querying)

Comment: Have you considered creating database views on top of your database tables and mapping your entities to these views?

Comment: I know a view can be used as if it was a table, and that might solve our problem, but alas we are restricted. They don't like us messing with the database, even if it is only adding a view. For now, we have to use the database read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [Multiple Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables) via [Secondary Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTables.html) Annotation/Mapping in your wrapper class?

This way your wrapper can be composed of the four underlying tables but offer a cleaner interface to the application.

Comment: 9 months later, exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad I was able to find your question.

Comment: A constructor expression might be handy here too-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271305/jpql-constructor-expression-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexceptiontable-i

Comment: Yes, I used this kind of constructor expression to create these wrapper-objects. But I needed this answer to use them as input to other queries.