# Primefaces datatable get selected row as type arrayList

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Here is my table in primefaces datatable:

(I'm using `hibernate` to get table rows)

[image]

code:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myCardBean.userCard(userBean.currentUser.id)}"/>
...
<p:dataTable id="books" value="#{myCardBean.booksList}" var="book" selectionMode="single"
             selection="#{myCardBean.selectedOrder}" rowKey="#{book[0]}">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myCardBean.onRowSelect}"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{myCardBean.onRowUnselect}"/>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Order ID</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[0]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Book Title</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[1]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Book Cost</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[2]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Author</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[3]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Order Date </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[4]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">QTY</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[5]}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Total Price</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{book[6]}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here is `MyCardBean` class:

```
@Autowired
private BookDao bookDao;
private Object[] selectedOrder;
private List<Object[]> orderBookInfo;

public List<Book> userCard(String uID) {
    booksList =  bookDao.getOrderAndBookInfo(uID).list(); //returns array list of orderId, book title, book cost,...
    return booksList;
}


public List<Object> getOrderBookInfo() {
    return orderBookInfo;
}

public void setOrderBookInfo(List<Object[]> orderBookInfo) {
    this.orderBookInfo = orderBookInfo;
}

public Object[] getSelectedOrder() {
    return selectedOrder;
}

public void setSelectedOrder(Object[] selectedOrder) {
    this.selectedOrder = selectedOrder;
}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("row selected, " + event.getObject());
}

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("row Unselected");
}
```

Each row of table is an `java.util.ArrayList` type.

I got no exception in row selection, But it displays like this:

```
row selected, [Ljava.lang.Object;@c25754e
```

(I tried `Object` type instead of `Object[]` for `selectedOrder`, but got the same result)

Why it can't displays correctly when i select a row?, like:

```
3 , ontellijidea , 20000.0 , Mr aa , 2015-05-03 , 5 , 100000.0
```

**UPDATE**

```
public SQLQuery getOrderAndBookInfo(String userId) {
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT " +
            " orders.id, book.title, book.cost, book.author, orders.orderDate, orderitem.quantity, orderitem.totalPrice " +
            "FROM book" +
            " INNER JOIN orderitem ON book.id = orderitem.book_id " +
            "  INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitem.orders_id " +
            "WHERE user_id = :userID ");
    sqlQuery.setString("userID", userId);
    return sqlQuery;
}
```

Model classes:

[image]

Comment: This `[Ljava.lang.Object;` is the name for `Object[].class`. This means that  this line `booksList =  bookDao.getTitleCostQty(uID).list();` returns a `List<Object[]>` which you incorrectly assumed that it returned a `List<Book>`. It does not. Have a JPQL/criteria return a correct generic list - `List<Book>` or change the type of `private List<Book> booksList;` to `private List<Object[]> booksList;`. The approach is requirement-dependent. (You might be doing like this `SELECT b.bookId, b.bookTitle, b.author FROM Book b`. You however, need `SELECT b FROM Book b`. This will return a `List<Book>`)

Comment: @Tiny In `getTitleCostQty` the `orderID` , `bookTitle` , `bookCost` , ... columns come from multiple tables by joining them. So i think i cant defined a `unit` type it.

Comment: @Tiny I actually not sure what should be the type of `bookList` variable. because it's actually contains the joining of `Orders` and `Book` and `OrderItem` and `User` table.

Comment: The type is `List<Object[]>` ((default). You can also have `List<Tuple>`). If the result list is a combination of multiple tables (which are entities in turn), then you will need to map the result list to an appropriate result class with appropriate properties and parameterized constructor(s). The list of columns in the query statement must match the constructor parameters in number, order and type. See [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12286281/1391249). (You can do this using a JPQL/criteria query without firing a native SQL statement directly on the back-end database).

Comment: `SELECT NEW example.EmpMenu(e.name, e.department.name)` in that link is a constructor (fully qualified name) in the `EmpMenu` class with appropriate parameters matching the query statement in number, order and (data)type.

Comment: @Tiny I made final changes in code. Now looks better.

Comment: @Tiny I defined `List<Object[]>` for `orderBookInfo` . But i still get the same result.

Comment: Return type here `public List<Book> userCard(String uID)` is still `List<Book>`. (I personally would not use `List<Object[]>`, by the way).

Comment: You can type-cast `event.getObject()` to `List<Object[]>`, if you need it (`List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) event.getObject()`) and then use the list - you can do whatever you want to do with the list.

Comment: All your JSF questions/problems asked/faced so far are all caused by only one simple problem: your Hibernate query returns an awful `List<Object[]>` instead of a sensible and transparent `List<Book>` model. Really, fix that query, or you'll never stop facing problems and asking questions which all boil down to the same answer. If you can't fix the Hibernate query for some unclear reason, just perform the mapping manually in the service layer, if necessary via a DTO.

Comment: @BalusC As you see in `getOrderAndBookInfo()` , i get multiple columns from multiple tables (classes) , and not from `Book` . They comes from `Book` , `Orders` and `OrderItem` tables. So i can't have `list<Book.Order,OrderItem[]>` . and this is my main problem.

Comment: Just fix your model to be a `List<OrderItem>` and make `Book` and `Order` properties of `OrderItem`. Or perhaps a `List<Order>` and give `Order` a `List<OrderItem>` property, not sure how exactly your DB model looks like and how exactly you'd like to present it.

Comment: @BalusC I put the model tables.

Comment: @BalusC Now the `orderBookInfo` is a `List<Orders>` , now how assign each table columns? `orderBookInfo = (List<Orders>) bookDao.getOrderAndBookInfo(uID).list();`

Comment: @Tiny: `event.getObject()` is and `Object[]` and not an `List<Object[]>`. Please be careful what you tell this user (some difficulties with basic java knowledge)

Comment: @Kukeltje : I accept my mistake happily. My fingers on the keyboard did not support me. The reason might be simple : The daily routine is 18 to 20 hours a day or even more sometimes. The brain just goes out of energy sometimes, sorry.

Comment: @Tiny: yep totally understand. I often write (to short) answers on my phone late at night and then in the morning I shoked by what I wrote (both spelling and content quality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event.getObject() is an Object[], not an arraylist that is what the [L in `[Ljava.lang.Object;@c25754e` means, so it is exactly as what should be and your subject/title is wrong.

Java does,for obious reasons, not know how to print this so it prints what you see. You most likely did not try to print event.getObject()[0].

And again, this is all very basic java stuff that if you takea goood (very good) look at what is actually happening can be found with some simple searches on the internet. Please, as stated multiple times now learn basic java first and learn some troubleshooting

Comment: @cvcvcvcv: did it help? Was I right?