# Dynamic query with @Query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Specifications in my Spring Boot app and can filter result by different filter options. However, I need to use special filter with `@Query` in my repository method and as far as I see, I cannot build a dynamic WHERE clause in this query.

There are also QueryDSL and CriteriaAPI options, but I cannot find an example for using them in `@Query`.

So, is it possible to dynamically build WHERE clause or create filter for the query in `@Query`? Here is my method:

```
// there are more filters that omitted for brevity 

@Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r WHERE r.title LIKE %:text%")
Page<Recipe> findByFields(@Param("text") String text);
```

I tried to use my specification in this method, but it is not possible to use them with `@Query` :((

**Update:**

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private HealthLabel healthLabel;

    // code omitted for brevity

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredient {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientId recipeIngredientId = new RecipeIngredientId();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("recipeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("ingredientId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here is also my enum that I cannot filter by:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum HealthLabel {

    DEFAULT("Default"),
    EGG_FREE("Egg-free"),
    VEGETARIAN("Vegetarian"),
    WHEAT_FREE("Wheat-free");

    private String label;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this with `@Query`? What prevents you from using the specifications? I don't really see the issue.

Comment: Use Hibernate ORM classes for SQL-based server, not need this hard-try. But, if you want the parameter directly use like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#1-jpql-2

Comment: @Numichi Thanks for help. Actually I created a custom filter using Specifications before asking the question. But, although it works well in my Recipe entity, I cannot make it filter related entities e.g. Ingredient. I use Hibernate and actually I implemented all the necessary relationship between entities properly. When I retrieve a Recipe data, I can receive Ingredient data belonging to this Recipe, but I am not sure if I can filter data on Ingredient as well.

Comment: @Numichi Here is the approach that I followed, could  you just have a look at and inform me if it is possible to filter Recipes having an ingredient with name? https://blog.piinalpin.com/2022/04/searching-and-filtering-using-jpa-specification/

Comment: You only state you need to use a special filter with a query not why you think this is a must. From the partially additional information in your comments (I would suggest to rewrite your question instead with a full problem statement instead) there is nothing preventing you from using a `Specification` (which is basically a criteria query) to achieve what you want. From what I read is you want `Recipe` instances that contain an `Ingredient` with a `name` like `something`. Using the `Criteria` API (and thus `Specification`) this is very much doable.

Comment: At this step, I am not sure if your answer can be applied to solve the problem. Because, in this case I am not sure how should I build my filter request. Can you have a look at **Filter by Name and Sort by Release Date ASC** section on [this](https://blog.piinalpin.com/2022/04/searching-and-filtering-using-jpa-specification/) article that I followed. And what do you think about the filter request? What should I use as `key` parameter in order to filter recipes by both `Recipe.title` and `Ingredient.name` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from using a `Specification` (which is basically the `Criteria` API but easier to use). You basically want the dynamic version of the following JPQL.

```sql
SELECT r FROM Recipe r 
JOIN r.recipeIngredients ri 
JOIN ri.ingredient i
WHERE i.name LIKE :name
```

Now if you can write it in JPQL you can also use the `Criteria` API to write it (generally speaking).

```
public static Specification<Recipe> findByIngredientName(String name) {
  return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
     Join<Recipe, RecipeIngredient> ingredients = root.join("ingredients");
     Join< RecipeIngredient, Ingredient> ingredient = ingredients.join("ingredient");      
     return criteriaBuilder.like(ingredient.get("name"), "%" + name + "%"); 
  };
}
```

That is the specification to retrieve a `Recipe` containing an `Ingredient` with a `name` `like` something. You need 2 joins no query just a join.

You can now even combine multiple predicates by using `Predicate.and`. So if you create another `Predicate` for the `Recipe.name` you can just chain them together, JPA will handle the rest.

```
public static Specification<Recipe> findName(String name) {
  return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> { 
     return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("title"), "%" + name + "%"); 
  };
}
```

```
Specification<Recipe> specs = findByName("recipe").and(findByIngredientName("ingredient"));
recipeRepository.findAll(specs);
```

That is all you need. What and how you receive those parameters that is up to you how you build the request/response objects and is highly subjective. If you want a sort order use the `findAll` which takes a `Specification` and a `Sort`

```
Specification<Recipe> specs = findByName("recipe").and(findByIngredientName("ingredient"));
recipeRepository.findAll(specs, Sort.by("title"));
```

The above will generate a SQL in the form of

```
SELECT recipesapp0_.id as id1_1_, recipesapp0_.title as title2_1_ FROM recipes_application$recipe recipesapp0_ 
INNER JOIN recipes_application$recipe_ingredient recipeingr1_ ON recipesapp0_.id=recipeingr1_.recipe_id 
INNER JOIN recipes_application$ingredient recipesapp2_ ON recipeingr1_.ingredient_id=recipesapp2_.id 
WHERE (recipesapp0_.title like ?) AND (recipesapp2_.name like ?) ORDER BYrecipesapp0_.title ASC
```

**NOTE:** Next time when someone asks for clarification of your use-case please give it instead of being unfriendly to them!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250211/discussion-on-answer-by-m-deinum-dynamic-query-with-query-in-spring-data-jpa).

Answer (score 0):

`@Query` can only do static queries.

If you want something more dynamic you have to use another feature, for example [`Specifications`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) or even fall back to [custom method implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I created a custom filter using Specifications before asking the question. **But**, although it works well in my `Recipe` entity, I cannot make it filter related entities e.g. `Ingredient`. I use Hibernate and actually I implemented all the necessary relationship between entities properly. When I retrieve a Recipe data, I can receive Ingredient data belonging to this Recipe, but I am not sure if I can filter data on Ingredient as well.

Comment: Here is the approach that I followed, could  you just have a look at and inform me if it is possible to filter Recipes having an ingredient with name? https://blog.piinalpin.com/2022/04/searching-and-filtering-using-jpa-specification/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r WHERE r.title LIKE %?1%")
Page<Recipe> findByFields(String text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried similar approach and does not work. Nevertheless, voted up