# Spring Data JPA Select Distinct

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I need to build a `select distinct a.address from Person a` (where address is a Address entity inside the Person) kind of query.

I am using Specification to dynamically build my where clause and using the `findAll(Specification<T>)` function to get the result. The problem is I can not use specification to build my select clause and hence can not use `findAll(Spcification)` function.

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 10):

As it's the top question in google, I'll post the answer here.

In the specification you have access to query, so you can do

```
query.distinct(true);
```

Full example, which results in such SQL emitted:

> 2015-04-27 12:03:39 EEST [7766-759] postgres@sales LOG:  execute
>   : SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.WEBNAME, t1.WEBORDER,
>   t1.PVGROUPPARENT_ID, t1.SITE_ID FROM PRODUCTVARIANT t0, PVGROUP t1
>   WHERE ((t0.PRODUCTTYPE_ID = $1) AND (t0.PVGROUP_ID = t1.ID))
>   2015-04-27 12:03:39 EEST [7766-760] postgres@sales DETAIL: 
>   parameters: $1 = '4608bdc9-d0f2-4230-82fd-b0f776dc2cfd'

```
public static Specification<PVGroup> byProductType(final ProductType pt) {
        return (final Root<PVGroup> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {

            query.distinct(true);
            final CollectionJoin<PVGroup, ProductVariant> jPV = root.join(PVGroup_.productVariant);

            final Path<ProductType> ptPath = jPV.get(ProductVariant_.productType);

            return builder.equal(ptPath, pt);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue, so in case it would help someone, this is what I did:

The Specification is being translated to the where clause, and the `findAll(Specification<T>)` function is creating its own select clause. So there is no way we can fix this by somehow using the `findAll(Specification<T>)` function.
I already had custom repository which extends `SimpleJpaRepository`, so I've added a new method:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Object> findDistinctValues(Specifications<T> spec, String columnName) {
        return getQuery(spec, columnName).getResultList();
    }

    protected TypedQuery<Object> getQuery(Specification<T> spec, final String distinctColumnName) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object> query = builder.createQuery(Object.class);
        Root<T> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, query);

        if (null != distinctColumnName) {
            query.distinct(true);
            query.multiselect(root.get(distinctColumnName));
        }

        // We order by the distinct column, Asc
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(distinctColumnName)));

        return em.createQuery(query);
    }
```

`applySpecificationToCriteria` is in the `SimpleJpaRepository` class.

Now you can use the `findDistinctValues` method.

Comment: `applySpecificationToCriteria` is a private method in the SimpleJpaRepository class. You can't use it.

Comment: As far as I remember, I copied the method to my custom repository.

Answer (score 4):

Good! You can use `distinct` in `JPQL` and also for specific column. It is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231118/using-distinct-keyword-in-jpa-on-individual-columns). 
Reference [Using DISTINCT in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346181/using-distinct-in-jpa)

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty to solution is to filter the result using a `Set`:

```
Set<...> set = new HashSet<...>( findAll( ... ) )
```

and be sure that `equals()` and `hashCode()` are relevantly implemented on the domain class :-)

Cheers,

Comment: If you use pageable this will mess up the size and offsets

Answer (score -2):

Will this work ?

`List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByAddress(String lastname, String firstname);`

followed by iterating thru the list and using Person.getAddress() ?