# JPA select from select distinct

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to execute the following SQL query writing native query in JPA:

```
            SELECT id FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row FROM table
            ) WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

In the Query annotation I wrote:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(e.id), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS row FROM Table e) t WHERE row BETWEEN ? AND ?")
```

but I have syntax errors here `FROM (SELECT`.
Please, can you help me?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943574/spring-data-jpa-select-distinct

Comment: Or maybe you need to add an alias:  SELECT id FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row FROM table
            )  t WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 10;

Comment: you have missed to add  `nativeQuery=true`. please add it  your end of query.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgot `nativeQuery=true`
Try this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(e.id), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS row FROM Table e) t WHERE row BETWEEN ? AND ?", nativeQuery = true)
```